# Displaying UTF-8 in Javascript Generated HTML (e.g. pound sign)

Tags: javascript, encoding, utf-8, mime

I've got a bizzaire problem and I've looked through all the similar questions and still not been able to solve it.  I am decoding a MIME e-mail message in javascript and see =C2=A3 which means two characters 0xC2 and 0xA2 to make the UTF-8 British pound sign.

I've set the meta charset = UTF-8 in the document but it still doesn't display as a pound sign in the rendered html document.  Page Info says the page is rendered as UTF-8... if that's the case why isn't the pound sign and nbsp's showing properly?

I'm using the following code to decode the string:

```
s.replace(/=[\r\n]+/g, "").replace(/=[0-9A-F]{2}/gi, function(v) {
    return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(v.substr(1), 16));
})
```

Comment: I'm using the following code to decode the string s:

`s.replace(/=[\r\n]+/g, "").replace(/=[0-9A-F]{2}/gi, function(v) { 
return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(v.substr(1),16)); 
});`

Comment: Yeah, that's too simplistic. The bytes `C2 A3` *together* form one Unicode character encoded in UTF-8; `String.fromCharCode` expects a single Unicode code point to generate one character. Doing two individual bytes in a row won't do it. You'll need to be aware of the UTF-8 encoding specifics while decoding this text to make sure you're decoding `=C2=A3` together into one number which you pass to `String.fromCharCode`. That may be quite a bit of code, I'd expect there to be libraries already available for such things.

Comment: gotcha thanks for your help - you've just resolved several days work!

Answer (score 0):

decoding code here:

https://gist.github.com/boushley/5471599

A sequence of bytes needs to be decoded properly into UTF8.

Comment: Please post the code here for posterity, links tend to rot. Maybe a complete solution from MIME text to chars for extra points. ;)

Answer (score 0):

That's too simplistic a decoding algorithm. The bytes `C2 A3` *together* form one Unicode character encoded in UTF-8; `String.fromCharCode` expects a single Unicode code point to generate one character. Doing two individual bytes in a row won't do it. You'll need to be aware of the UTF-8 encoding specifics while decoding this text to make sure you're decoding `=C2=A3` together into one number which you pass to `String.fromCharCode`. That may be quite a bit of code, I'd expect there to be libraries already available for such things.

For example, see this code from [here](https://gist.github.com/boushley/5471599) (posting what you have found here for posterity):

```
function decodeUtf8(arrayBuffer) {
  var result = "";
  var i = 0;
  var c = 0;
  var c1 = 0;
  var c2 = 0;

  var data = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);

  // If we have a BOM skip it
  if (data.length >= 3 && data[0] === 0xef && data[1] === 0xbb && data[2] === 0xbf) {
    i = 3;
  }

  while (i < data.length) {
    c = data[i];

    if (c < 128) {
      result += String.fromCharCode(c);
      i++;
    } else if (c > 191 && c < 224) {
      if( i+1 >= data.length ) {
        throw "UTF-8 Decode failed. Two byte character was truncated.";
      }
      c2 = data[i+1];
      result += String.fromCharCode( ((c&31)<<6) | (c2&63) );
      i += 2;
    } else {
      if (i+2 >= data.length) {
        throw "UTF-8 Decode failed. Multi byte character was truncated.";
      }
      c2 = data[i+1];
      c3 = data[i+2];
      result += String.fromCharCode( ((c&15)<<12) | ((c2&63)<<6) | (c3&63) );
      i += 3;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```